# Correct usage/distinction in these examples

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning, colons

The score has a real unique sound with interesting vocals; *the score is also well produced and professional.*

Our law firm is one of the Internet's most prolific copyright experts: *firms that catch users downloading content from peer-to-peer networks will face prosecution.*

We are unable to say how long it has been here — *it may be 30 years or much more.*

What I found was like what a dog had unearthed — *what looked like an old bag of cement.*

**What is the distinction between the semi-colon,em-dash, and colon when used to connect related complete sentences?  To my eyes these are all the same. What is the correct use?**

Answer (score 1):

A **semi-colon** is used between two independent clauses. It signifies a strong relationship between those clauses. Should be used sparingly and is often used incorrectly (I don't think you used a good example).

A **colon** is used, primarily to introduce a list, including 1-word (or 1-noun phrase) lists. (I don't think your colon example was strong, either).

An **em-dash** is used, in some contexts, to introduce *asides*, that is, non-germane or tangential information. The specific use between hyphens and en and em dashes depend on your chosen style (Your second example is not strong, the first one, maybe).

[The Punctuation Guide](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/) has some good things to say on this point, as well.

Comment: em-dash What would be a good example in your opinion.